Hpux 10.20: auditing enabled and report..nothing
I have enabled auditing on hpux 10.20
vim /etc/rc.config.d/auditing

AUDITING=1
PRI_AUDFILE=/.secure/etc/audfile1
PRI_SWITCH=1000
SEC_AUDFILE=/.secure/etc/audfile2
SEC_SWITCH=1000
AUDEVENT_ARGS1="-P -F -e moddac -e login -e admin"
AUDEVENT_ARGS2=""
AUDEVENT_ARGS3=""
AUDOMON_ARGS="-p 20 -t 1 -w 90"

start auditing
audsys -c /.secure/etc/audfile1 -x /.secure/etc/audfile2 -s 1000 -z 1000

i reboot and..
audisp -u root
users and aids:
root
0
All events are selected.
All ttys are selected.
Selecting successful & failed events.
TIME              PID E  EVENT   PPID    AID       RUID       RGID       EUID       EGID TTY

as you can see no events are reported, why?
